# How to append or wrap text around specific tag

Tags: jquery, append

In the select menu I have various bbcodes. I was wondering how I can wrap/append the user input from `#message` inside of a bbcode tag like this [b]USER-HAS-TYPED-SOMETHING[/b] and output that end results to `<pre id="display"></pre>`

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/ypmfK/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enableuserreply').click(function() {

        var dis = $(this).prop('checked') ? "" : "disabled";

        $("#usernames").prop('disabled', dis);
    });
    $('#enapletexteffect').click(function() {

        var dis = $(this).prop('checked') ? "" : "disabled";

        $("#boxcode").prop('disabled', dis);
        $("#colors").prop('disabled', dis);
    });

    $('#message').keyup(function(){   

        if ($('#enableuserreply').is(':checked')) {
            var msg = $("#usernames option:selected").text() + " has typed ";

            var boxcode = $("#boxcode option:selected").attr('value');

            var  message = $('#message').val();
            msg = msg + message ;

            var boxcodeArr = new Array();

            if(boxcode){
                boxcode = $.trim(boxcode.replace('[', '<'));
                boxcode = $.trim(boxcode.replace('[/', ',</'));
                boxcode = $.trim(boxcode.replace(']', '>'));
                boxcode = $.trim(boxcode.replace(']', '>'));
                boxcodeArr = boxcode.split(',');  
                 msg = boxcodeArr[0] + msg + boxcodeArr[1] ;         
            }

            $("#display").html(msg);  
            var color = $("#colors option:selected").attr('value');

            if(color) {
               $("#display").css('color', color);
            }


        }

    });
});
```

this is the complete code . it is working :)

Comment: WHOA!!!! thank you so much can you put this in a jsfiddle demo. i tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: it works , first select a user , then it will work , copy an paste this code in your jsfiddle demo and run it , i tried the code on your demo , tell me if there is any probs :)

Comment: i tested it again in your demo , it works fine :) , but sory i did not write any code for the clear button :(

Comment: yes!! it works but can you make some changes? i only wanted it to work for the "Text Effect" part not the name. Also instead of applying the effects to what the user types in can you make it return the code with the text? like this -> [b]some text[/b]